# Error in kids_node(node)[[i]] : subscript out of bounds in partykit

Tags: r, party

I'm trying to replicate the procedure proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844830/how-to-specify-split-in-a-decision-tree-in-r-programming) on [my data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oo3oYCVD8KHhxqyWUQDh75dx0Jd1bSq_/view?usp=share_link).

`target` is the categorical variable that I want to predict while I would force the first split of the classification tree to be done according to `split.variable` (categorical too). Due to the object characteristics, indeed, if `split.variable` is 1 `target` can be only 1, while if it is 0, `target` can be 0 or 1. This leads to:

```
> table(training_set$target, training_set$split.variable)
     0  1
  0 69  0
  1 59 56
```

I'm able to create `tr1` and `tr2` (`tr3` returns an error [`Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`] because -if I'm correct- it's "empty", so no need of it [see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385219/error-in-contrasts-tmp-value-contr-funs1-isofnn-with-an-obviou) post]).

```
tr1 <- ctree(target ~ split.variable,     data = training_set, maxdepth = 1) # create the first split at comp_cat
tr2 <- ctree(target ~ split.variable + ., data = training_set,  # then the left branch...
             subset = predict(tr1, type = "node") == 2)

fix_ids <- function(x, startid = 1L) {
  id <- startid - 1L
  new_node <- function(x) {
    id <<- id + 1L
    if(is.terminal(x)) return(partynode(id, info = info_node(x)))
    partynode(id,
              split = split_node(x),
              kids = lapply(kids_node(x), new_node),
              surrogates = surrogates_node(x),
              info = info_node(x))
  }
  
  return(new_node(x))   
}

no <- node_party(tr1)
no$kids <- list(
  fix_ids(node_party(tr2), startid = 2L)
  #, fix_ids(node_party(tr3), startid = 5L)
  )
no # visualize the structure    
[1] root
|   [2] V2 <= 1
|   |   [3] V15 <= -2.489 *
|   |   [4] V15 > -2.489 *

mdf <- model.frame(target ~ split.variable + ., data = training_set)
tr <- party(no, 
            data = mdf,
            fitted = data.frame(
              "(fitted)" = fitted_node(no, data = mdf),
              "(response)" = model.response(mdf),
              check.names = FALSE),
            terms = terms(mdf), )
```

but, running `party(...)` I get the following error:

```
Error in kids_node(node)[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The only reference to such error that I was able to find is [this](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/1490) Github issue.

Here the `traceback`:

```
8: is.terminal(node)
7: fitted_node(kids_node(node)[[i]], data, vmatch, obs[indx], perm)
6: fitted_node(no, data = mdf)
5: data.frame(`(fitted)` = fitted_node(no, data = mdf), `(response)` = model.response(mdf), 
       check.names = FALSE)
4: party(no, data = mdf, fitted = data.frame(`(fitted)` = fitted_node(no, 
       data = mdf), `(response)` = model.response(mdf), check.names = FALSE), 
       terms = terms(mdf), )
3: .is.positive.intlike(x)
2: .traceback(x, max.lines = max.lines)
1: traceback(party(no, data = mdf, fitted = data.frame(`(fitted)` = fitted_node(no, 
       data = mdf), `(response)` = model.response(mdf), check.names = FALSE), 
       terms = terms(mdf), ))
```

I don't get if it is an issue related to the missing branch, to `mlr` or to any other particular situation related to my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your issue**

The problem is that you in `no$kids` you just define the first subtree but just leave out the second subtree (consisting of just a terminal node). You can simply set this up with the correct id as `partynode(5L)`, i.e.,

```
no$kids <- list(
  fix_ids(node_party(tr2), startid = 2L),
  partynode(5L)
)
```

This is already sufficient here. In case the node your subsetting would have an `info` associated with it (not the case here), you would also have to pass that on:

```
no$kids <- list(
  fix_ids(node_party(tr2), startid = 2L),
  partynode(5L, info = info_node(kids_node(tr1$node)[[2L]]))
)
```

After that you can follow the steps from the other answer to set up your `constparty` object.

**More generally**

I don't understand why you are doing this in the first place. If `split.variable` = 1 always implies `target` = 1, then there seems no point in modeling that. So why not just model the subset of the data with `split.variable` = 0?

But even if you decide that you want to model it, `ctree` chooses `split.variable` as the first split anyway. So all of this manual forcing of the split does not seem to be necessary in the first place.

```
training_set <- read.csv("training_set.txt")
training_set <- transform(training_set,
  target = factor(target),
  split.variable = factor(split.variable)
)
tr <- ctree(target ~ ., data = training_set)
tr
## Model formula:
## target ~ split.variable + var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + 
##     var6 + var7 + var8 + var9 + var10 + var11 + var12 + var13 + 
##     var14 + var15 + var16 + var17 + var18 + var19 + var20 + var21 + 
##     var22 + var23 + var24 + var25 + var26 + var27 + var28 + var29
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] split.variable in 0
## |   |   [3] var13 <= -2.489: 1 (n = 28, err = 32.1%)
## |   |   [4] var13 > -2.489: 0 (n = 54, err = 25.9%)
## |   [5] split.variable in 1: 1 (n = 48, err = 0.0%)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    2
## Number of terminal nodes: 3
plot(tr)
```

[image: Visualization of constparty object created by plot(tr)]

Comment: great, many thanks! being part of a bigger piece of code, I'm willing to force the manual split in order to be sure it goes that way. Nevertheless, it seems I have to get more confident with the whole package